# External Hard Drive is in read only mode

Tags: mount, windows, hard-drive

I have a external hard drive with windows 10 installed, but I use it like pen drive. When I turned on my PC, it was booted with windows in the usb hard drive and show a error. After that my hard drive just opend in read only mode in my ubuntu. How can I remove this lock? I readed that  windows close hard drive when is booting and if occour any error the hard drive continues in locked mode. I have to open my hard drive again to write files normally.

Comment: Look up how to run a SMART test on your external drive.